# How to check if not instance of some class in symfony2

Tags: php

I want to execute some functions if entity is member of few classes but not some.

There is a function called `instanceof`.

But is there something like

```
if ($entity !instanceof [User,Order,Product])
```

Comment: instanceof isn't a function, it's a keyword.  And no, there's nothing like that in PHP's language, you'd have to implement a function to do it yourself.

Comment: Đéo thằng nào có giải pháp ra hồn nhỉ

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Give them a common interface and then

```
if (!$entity instanceof ShopEntity)
```

or stay with

```
if (!$entity instanceof User && !$entity instanceof Product && !$entity instanceof Order)
```

I would avoid creating arbitrary functions just to save some characters at a single place. On the other side if you need it "too often", you may have a design flaw? (In the meaning of "too much edge cases" or such)

Comment: wouldn't it be better to `if (!($entity instanceof User))` ?

Comment: @DanFromGermany Doesn't make a difference. Maybe readability. It's up to you.

Comment: @KingCrunch Very conceptually confusing why it doesn't make a difference? I prefer Dragos' answer and rationalisation. It's the way I do it, as it just seems dirty to negate the instance you want to check before you've checked what it actually is.

Comment: @Jonathan See http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php At the end it's only about `$a+$b+$c` vs `($a+$b)+$c`. Ever tried `2**3**4 == (2**3)**4`? ;)

Comment: Be sure to import/use class you are checking with instanceof. Eg. for `if ( $entity instanceof Audio )` I need to have `use App\Entity\Audio;`. PHP won't throw error if you do not use class you are checking - but your if will never fire.

Answer (score 89):

PHP manual says: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php

```
!($a instanceof stdClass)
```

This is just a logical and "grammatically" correct written syntax.

```
!$class instanceof someClass
```

The suggested syntax above, though, is tricky because we are not specifying which exactly is the scope of the negation: the variable itself or the whole construct of `$class instanceof someclass`. We will only have to rely on the operator precendence here [Edited, thanks to @Kolyunya].

Comment: This is a cleaner solution. I'm sure half the people end up on this question started looking because `if (!$entity instanceof ShopEntity)` is not intuitive... Many of us use `!$entity` as `$entity === null`.

Comment: What do you mean by `We will only have to rely here on the smart implementation of the PHP parser.`? There is the language specification that clearly states that the `instanceof` operator has a higher precedence than the `!` operator.

Comment: @Kolyunya  readability, vs "hmm, that looks weird.. let me look up php's operator precedence... ok, that checks out"

Answer (score 15):

[PHP Operator Precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

`instanceof` operator is just before negation then this expression:

```
!$class instanceof someClass
```

is just right in PHP and this do that you expect.

Comment: As you mentioned, the keynote is that the precedence of the `instanceof` operator is higher than `!`, so the statement gives a true result. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

This function should do it:

```
function isInstanceOf($object, Array $classnames) {
    foreach($classnames as $classname) {
        if($object instanceof $classname){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

So your code is

```
if (!isInstanceOf($entity, array('User','Order','Product')));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function check($object) {
    $deciedClasses = [
        'UserNameSpace\User',
        'OrderNameSpace\Order',
        'ProductNameSpace\Product',
    ];

    return (!in_array(get_class($object), $allowedClasses));
}
```

Comment: This doesn't handle inheritance well.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try these

```
    $cls = [GlobalNameSpace::class,\GlobalNameSpaceWithSlash::class,\Non\Global\Namespace::class];
    if(!in_array(get_class($instance), $cls)){
        //do anything
    }
```